# how to add alternative row formatting in EPP Plus C# .XLSX download

Tags: c#, epplus

I am upgrading .xls download in .aspx page to .xlsx download using c# EppPlus. How can I add Alternative row background color like each other row has gray background ?

I am using the below code

```
public void DumpExcel(DataTable tbl)
{
    using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        //Create the worksheet
        ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");


        ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(tbl, true);



        using (ExcelRange rng = ws.Cells["A1:AA1"])
        {
            rng.Style.Font.Bold = false;
            rng.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid; //Set Pattern for the background to Solid
            rng.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.FromArgb(0, 51, 153));  //Set color to dark blue
            rng.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.White);
            rng.Style.Font.Size = 10;
        }



        // Add Word wrap
        for (int i = 1; i <= tbl.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            ws.Column(i).AutoFit();
            ws.Column(i).Width = 20;
            ws.Column(i).Style.WrapText = true;
            ws.Column(i).Style.VerticalAlignment = ExcelVerticalAlignment.Top;
            ws.Column(i).Style.Font.Size = 9;
        }


        //Write it back to the client
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=UserEntitleDLX.xlsx");
        Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: did you want the entire worksheet formatted? also please note my answer because that might be a much easier way to format it if you want it to be formatted as a table

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it should also be mentioned that there is an overload for LoadFromDataTable where you can pass a TableStyle like so

```
ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(tbl, true, TableStyles.Dark1);
```

If you want the tbl's area to be formatted from scratch then you could do something like this

```
for (var row = 1; row <= tbl.Rows.Count; row++)
{
    for (var column = 1; column <= tbl.Columns; column++)
    {
        ws.Cells[row, column].Style.Font.Bold = false;
        ws.Cells[row, column].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
        ws.Cells[row, column].Style.Font.Size = 10;

        ws.Cells[row, column].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(column%2 == 0
           ? Color.Blue
           : Color.Gray);
     }
}
```

Comment: Very good solution, adapted to my project and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 2):

Below piece of code did the job for me

```
  for (int row = ws.Dimension.Start.Row; row <= ws.Dimension.End.Row; row++)
                {
                    int pos = row % 2;
                    ExcelRow rowRange = ws.Row(row);
                    ExcelFill RowFill = rowRange.Style.Fill;
                    RowFill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                    switch (pos)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            RowFill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.White);

                            break;
                        case 1:
                            RowFill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.LightGray);
                            break;

                    }
                }
```

Comment: did you want the entire worksheet formatted? also please note my answer because that might be a much easier way to format it if you want it to be formatted as a table

Comment: @Grasshopper This a better solution in that we don't need to have `DataTable`. Would work all other scenarios `List<Object[]>` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variation of the given answers I use (as extension). My requirements required a subset of columns be colored, not the whole row, and with more than just two colors.

```
public static void ApplyBackgroundColorsPerRow(
    this ExcelWorksheet worksheet, 
    int startRow, int startColumn, int endRow, int endColumn, 
    List<System.Drawing.Color> colors)
{
    if (startRow <= endRow)
    {
        int numberOfColors = colors.Count;
        for (int row = startRow; row <= endRow; row++)
        {
            using (ExcelRange range = worksheet.Cells[row, startColumn, row, endColumn])
            {
                range.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                range.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(colors[(row - startRow) % numberOfColors]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternating white / gray (light gray is my recommendation over grey) would look like this:

```
worksheet.ApplyBackgroundColorsPerRow(
    startRow: 1,
    startColumn: 1,
    endRow: 20,
    endColumn: 5,
    colors: new List<System.Drawing.Color>()
    {
        System.Drawing.Color.White,
        System.Drawing.Color.LightGray
    }
);
```